# How to create REST client for external world REST services

Tags: java, jax-rs, rest-client

How can I create a rest client using JAX-RS Client fluent API for external world REST service?

E.g. suppose a service returns a person objects having two field name and age.

Whatever examples/tutorials I came across, they do the same thing as below snippet or they develop client in same project in order to replace String.class with person.class. How should I create independent client that will return me pojo of person.

```
String entity = client.target("http://example.com/rest")
        .path("resource/helloworld")
        .queryParam("greeting", "Hi World!")
        .request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
        .header("some-header", "true")
        .get(String.class);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Requesting an entity and mapping it to a Java class

Consider, for example, you are consuming a REST API which provides the following JSON when performing a `GET` request at `http://example.com/api/people/1`:

```json
{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "age": 25
}
```

The above JSON can be mapped to a Java class, defined as following:

```java
public class Person {

    private String name;

    private Integer age;

    // Constructor, getters and setters omitted
}
```

Using the JAX-RS Client API, the JSON can be requested as following, mapping the requested entity to the `Person` class:

```java
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
Person person = client.target("http://example.com/api")
                      .path("people").path("1")
                      .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                      .get(Person.class);

String name = person.getName();
Integer age = person.getAge();
```

The JAX-RS Client API is part of the [JAX-RS 2.0](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/jsr339-jaxrs-2.0-final-spec.pdf) specification and the reference implementation is [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/).

To parse JSON, Jersey comes with a set of extension modules for multiple frameworks that provide support for JSON processing and/or JSON-to-Java binding. Jersey supports [MOXy](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.moxy), [JSON-P](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.json-p), [Jackson](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson) and [Jettison](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jettison). For more details, have a look at the [documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json).

### Parsing the JSON manually

If, for some reason, you need to parse the requested entity manually, you can store the requested entity in a `String`:

```java
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
String json = client.target("http://example.com/api")
                    .path("people").path("1")
                    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .get(String.class);
```

And then the requested entity can be manually parsed using, for example, [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson):

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(json);

String name = node.path("name").asText();
Integer age = node.path("age").asInt();
```

To parse the JSON manually, you also could consider [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

### Alternatives

For alternatives on how to consume REST APIs with Java, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37390737/1426227).

Comment: Thanks for reply my question is about what standard practise fallowed whether its necessary that REST publisher should provide POJO of object returned from API or consumer need to create POJO depending upon JOSN reponce if you provide some example to read that will be great