# Consuming REST API with Java

Tags: java, rest, mean-stack

I have a management web application located on a remote server. This app was written using a MEAN stack and I have a list of all the RESTful routes necessary to connect to the web app.

I am writing a Java client application that needs to send and receive data from this management app. How do connect the client to the web application if I have the server's IP address and REST routes?

I imagine that I need to provide a URL connection to the server and the REST API file and then just call the route functions like `PUT` and `GET`.

Comment: You imagine correctly: Make an HTTP connection to the URL you're interested in and send the appropriate GET/POST request.

Comment: I suggest googling "Java how to call REST API" ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are plenty of libraries to consume REST applications in Java nowadays.

### The standard

The JAX-RS Client API ([`javax.ws.rs.client`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/package-summary.html) package), defined in the [JSR 339](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/jsr339-jaxrs-2.0-final-spec.pdf), is the standard way to consume REST web services in Java. Besides others, this specification is implemented by [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html) and [RESTEasy](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.16.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html).

### JAX-RS vendor specific proxy-based clients

Both [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html) and [RESTEasy](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.16.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html) APIs provide a proxy framework.

The basic idea is you can attach the [standard JAX-RS annotations to an interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jaxrs002.htm#GINNA), and then implement that interface by a resource class on the server side while reusing the same interface on the client side by dynamically generating an implementation of that using [`java.lang.reflect.Proxy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) calling the right low-level client API methods.

For more details, check the following:

- [Jersey proxy-based client API](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/client/proxy/package-summary.html)
- [RESTEasy proxy-based client API](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.13.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html#d4e2149)

### Other resources

There are a few other good options you may consider as alternative to the JAX-RS Client API:

- [Spring RestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html)
- [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)
- [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)
- [Netflix Feign](https://github.com/Netflix/feign)

Comment: Definitively Netflix Feign in one of the best options

Answer (score 0):

I would begin by reading the documentation for [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/), specifically the [Client](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html) portion. You will want to familiarize yourself with the `WebTarget` class and it is invoked (example from the documentation):

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
clientConfig.register(MyClientResponseFilter.class);
clientConfig.register(new AnotherClientFilter());

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
client.register(ThirdClientFilter.class);

WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://example.com/rest");
webTarget.register(FilterForExampleCom.class);
WebTarget resourceWebTarget = webTarget.path("resource");
WebTarget helloworldWebTarget = resourceWebTarget.path("helloworld");
WebTarget helloworldWebTargetWithQueryParam =
helloworldWebTarget.queryParam("greeting", "Hi World!");

Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder =
    helloworldWebTargetWithQueryParam.request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE);
invocationBuilder.header("some-header", "true");

Response response = invocationBuilder.get();
System.out.println(response.getStatus());
System.out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));
```