# Best practise to get database content from Wildfly

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, wildfly

We're running a Wildfly Server with an Java EE application that uses Hibernate. Now we need to implement a Java SE client that get some data from the database that Wildfly is using. What's the best practise for doing that? Using something like RPC? Or JAX-RS Client? The database itself is not accessible within the client. Thanks for helping!

Comment: That's a broad question and the answers tend to be primarily opinion-based. More details on your requirements would be nice to give you a good answer. However, I think you could could try a REST API with JAX-RS. To consume it, you could use a [REST client API](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37390737/1426227).

Answer (score 0):

It very much depends on how your server app is working and whether you have access to it's source code and ability to change it in case it doesn't have any web service implemented inside.

If your server app already does have any endpoints, the best choice would be to use those.

In case it doesn't have any endpoints at all, the most usual solution would be create JAX-RS web service on server application and use it in your Java SE client application.